# Error importing empty class, error TS2307: Cannot find module 'menu'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

I'm just trying to do import a simple, blank exported class. Im not sure why it can't find the file because it's in the same directory as the class importing it. I've searched google for similar error codes but no solutions have worked for me and its a relatively simple problem so im quite confused.

Error:

```
error TS2307: Cannot find module 'menu'
```

Folder structure:

```
node_modules/
src/
    entry.tsx
    menu.tsx
index.html
package-lock.json
package.json
tsconfig.json
webpack.config.js
```

entry.tsx

```
import menu from 'menu';
```

menu.tsx

```
export default class menu { }
```

webpack.config

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/js/entry.tsx',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: [ 'css-loader' ]
        })
      },
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
            filename: "bundle.css"
        }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'Custom template',
      template: 'index.html'
    })
  ]
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "helloworld",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Hello there",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack-dev-server",
    "build:prod": "webpack -p"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.19.0",
    "ts-loader": "^2.3.7",
    "typescript": "^2.5.3",
    "webpack": "^3.7.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^16.0.13",
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think Webpack tries to load Node packages if you don't include the relative path in your "include" lines.

Try changing this line in entry.tsx:

`import menu from 'menu';`

To this:

`import menu from './menu';`

Comment: Yes, this is correct. If you are not declaring relative pathing, it will assume the `import` is a separate module.

Comment: Thanks it worked! So if i say 'menu' it looks in the node_modules folder instead?

Comment: @user1337604 Correct.